# Перевод bool[64] в ulong

Tags: c#, массивы, .net, bool

У меня есть bool[64] массив, который нужно первевести в ulong. Я пол дня пытался, но у меня ничего не получилось. И пожалуйста напишите объяснение

Comment: Приведите Ваши попытки, что вы пытались. И что этот массив хранит? По каким правилам вы его в число переводите? Что конкретно не получается?

Comment: @tym32167 посмотрите предыдущий вопрос автора, сразу станет всё понятно :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Не факт, что идеальное решение, но рабочее.

```cs
private ulong ArrayToUInt64(bool[] arr)
{
    if (arr.Length < 64)
        throw new ArgumentException("Wrong array length", nameof(arr));
    ulong result = 0;
    ulong j = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < 64; i++)
    {
        if (arr[i])
            result |= j;
        j *= 2;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Точно надо объяснять? Простая двоичная арифметика. 1 - первый бит, 2 - второй, 4 - третий, 8 - четвертый, и так далее 63 раза умножить на два. Оператор `|` - двоичное сложение "или", включает бит.